# picbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle | Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, parallel-processing

I'm working on a C# Winforms project which loads images in a grid, I implemented parallelism and thread to learn a bit about it and there's something I can't figure out. I need to change the BorderStyle of a set of pictureboxes in run time, here's my code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Parallel.For(0, img.Count, i =>
        {
            Bitmap tmp_b = new Bitmap((System.Drawing.Image)img[i].RenderImage(0));
            imagenes[i] = tmp_b;
            Progress_Bar_Loading_Images.Invoke((Action)delegate { reportarprogreso(); });
        });
        for (int i = inicio_set; i < final_set; ++i)
        {
            picbox[i].Image = imagenes[i];
            picbox[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }
    });
```

The problem is in this line: `picbox[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;` I get an error message saying: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I think I know why this is happening but I'm not quite sure how to solve it. I tried putting the `for (int i = inicio_set; i < final_set; ++i)` outside the Task but the images won't get assigned to the pictureboxes since it's a different thread (main) and the images are not available until the task completes so I think I need to update the BorderStyle the same way I update the ProgressBar but not sure how that would be.

Thank you,

Matias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute the `for` loop in a different thread.

Change the `for` body to:

```
if (picbox[i].InvokeRequired)
{
    picbox[i].Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        picbox[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }));
}
else
{
      picbox[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}
```

or simply use `Async` - `Await` on the task;  make the caller method `Async` and the task:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(...)
```